# 去年の一年 grammar and meaning

Tags: grammar, time

My Japanese teacher said this sentence during a lesson:

> 去年の一年で七月が一番暑かったです。

Does this have the same meaning as:

> 去年で七月が一番暑かったです。

Are there any nuances between the two versions ?

Comment: In the second one, it should be 去年**は**七月が....

Comment: Wasn't it 去年一年で in the first version? I think that would be more common, although 去年の一年で wouldn't be wrong either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider their literal English translations, the nuance is the same as in English:

> 去年の一年で七月が一番暑かったです。
> Within (the year of) the past year July was the hottest.

> 去年で七月が一番暑かったです。
> Last year July was the hottest.

See how the emphasis slightly changes for the two phrases in English? The difference in the Japanese sentences are pretty much the same.